# How can I set rules in Firebase Realtime Database so that only registered users can write and read? .NET MAUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, maui

Im working with .Net Maui (6) & Firebase Authentication (3.7.2)
And i have this problem:

How can I set rules in RealtimeDatabase so that only registered users can write and read?, In other words, use the User ID (Uid) to Write and Read.

I'm trying to pass the User ID (Uid) parameter like this

```
string token = Preferences.Get("IdUser", "");
                FirebaseClient fb = new FirebaseClient(uri,
                    new FirebaseOptions
                    {
                        AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(token)


                    }) ;
```

But i get  access denied

EDIT-------

```
This is the rule

{
  "rules": {
    ".write": true,
    ".read": "auth.uid != null"

  }
}
```

And this is the URL generated by the C# of FirebaseOptions

https:///Products/.json?orderBy=%22$key%22&limitToFirst=10&auth=yw6yGKncMnf9oJul94UU9nTyg6J2

2 EDIT-------------

The authentication is running in this step of the login.

```
var user_email = Mail.Trim();
                var user_password = Password;

                var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(Literals.FirebaseStringProvider));
                var auth = await authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(user_email, user_password);
                var isValid = auth.User.IsEmailVerified;

                string idUser = auth.User.LocalId;
                string userName = auth.User.DisplayName;
                string refreshToken = auth.RefreshToken;
                string userImage = auth.User.PhotoUrl;
                string aurhToken = auth.FirebaseToken;

                var db = authProvider.GetUserAsync(auth.FirebaseToken);
                
                if (isValid)
                {
                    Preferences.Set("RefreshToken", refreshToken);
                    Preferences.Set("UserName", userName);
                    Preferences.Set("IdUser", idUser);
                    Preferences.Set("UserEmail", user_email);
                    Preferences.Set("UserProfilePic", userImage);
                    Preferences.Set("EspecialToken", aurhToken);
```

I am saving in the application preferences what the authentication returns to me. Then, in the reading, I use the following code where I have saved the "LocalId", "RefreshToken", and "FirebaseToken" in the token.

```
string token = Preferences.Get("IdUser", "");
                FirebaseClient fb = new FirebaseClient("https://uri/",
                    new FirebaseOptions
                    {
                        AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(token)


                    }) ;


                IdProductos = new List<string>();
                var getListUsers = await fb
                    .Child("Products")
                    .OrderByKey()
                    .LimitToFirst(10)
                    .OnceAsync<IdProductos>();
```

The resulting URL is:

https:///Products/.json?orderBy="$key"&limitToFirst=10&auth=yw6yGKncMnf9oJul94UU9nTyg6J2

According to the URL, I have 2 ways to do it, with access_token and ID_token, apparently my code responds to the second option. (yw6yGKncMnf9oJul94UU9nTyg6J2 corresponds to the UID of my user registered in Firebase Authentication)

Comment: Are you asking how to [let authenticated users access the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#realtime-database_1)? If you're struggling to make that work, edit your question to show the rules that you have (that are rejecting the write), the code that is getting rejected, and have the code prove that it meets the conditions of your security rules (i.e. log the UID of the signed in user right before accessing the database).

Comment: If the client you're using tries to access that URL, it'll have to pass authentication credentials as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth None of your code shows yet how the user is authenticated, so how the app meets the `auth.uid != null` rule of your database.

Comment: Did you cheked the official document above?